# finding by symbol then multipling

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel problem. column a contains values EG $123, €123 and £123.
I want to add a column that will search for the currency symbol then multiply the £ by 1.49 and the € + $ by 1. any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are these numbers with a mask or are they text.

Comment: All numbers (numbers, dates, times, currency etc) in Excel are held as doubles regardless of how they are formatted. So you may use Value2 and format conversion may not be required.

As per @Charles Williams
.Value2 gives you the underlying value of the cell (could be empty, string, error, number (double) or boolean)

.Value gives you the same as .Value2 except if the cell was formatted as currency or date it gives you a VBA currency


For more details please see [Text vs Value vs Value2](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you take the help of a helper column then first we can identify
   the currency by the UDF placed in the code section.. I have identified currency in column C while Column A Contains the formatted currency values.
2. In column B, I did the simple multiplication as I know as per my
   experience that currency format does not come into picture. Formula
   used in B2 is `=A2*$F$1`It is for testing purposes only.
3. Then in Column D2, I used the Nested IF formula and compared
   currency value in column C2 to Currency value in E1 which was Symbol
   inserted for true and correct recognition. The following formula is
   to be entered into Cell D2 and then copied down. It takes care of 3
   currencies in Nested IF statement.

   ```
    =IF(C2="$",A2*$F$1,IF(C2="€",A2*$F$1,A2*$F$3))
   ```

**UDF**

```
   Function GetCurrency(Rng As Range) As String
       If IsNumeric(Left(Rng.Text, 1)) Then
           GetCurrency = ""
       Else
           GetCurrency = Left(Rng.Text, 1)
      End If
```

Snapshot of sample data and results is placed below.

```
[![snapshot showing data and results][1]][1]
```

[image]